# Возможно ли в JavaScript обратиться к нескольким id через DOM + регулярное выражение?!

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Например, существуют элементы с идентификаторами:

```
index1
index2
index3
```

Хочу разом поменять фон им всем. Представляю себе это примерно так:

```
var reg = new RegExp("\d");

document.getElementById('index' + reg).style.background='#000';
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно? :)

upd: Количество элементов - неизвестно. А можно как-нибудь без jQuery обойтись?

Comment: Можно сделать функцию-обертку, как например здесь:  
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/getelementbyid-regexp  
Но это очень низкопроизводительно. Хотя можно создать заранее кэш всех элементов с ИД и делать выборку из кэша- это будет чуть быстрее.

Answer (score 3):

Если известно что элементов n:

```
index1
index2
index3
indexn
```

то:

```
var n = 5; // 5 элементов
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++){
   document.getElementById('index' + i).style.background='#000';
}
```

Comment: @Rules будь внимательней, у тебя отработает 4 элемента, т.к. условие "меньше пяти". Здесь нужен знак "меньше либо равно" (<=).

Comment: Спасибо, @lampa - исправил!

Answer (score 2):

На jQuery:

```
$('#index1, #index2, #index3').css("background-color","red");
```

Чистый CSS:

```
#index1, #index2, #index3
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Обыкновенный `getElementById` не принимает регулярных выражений, так что без jQuery вам понадобится 3 запроса.

---

UPD:
Если количество элементов неизвестно, лучше пойти прямым путём, дать им всем общий `class` и воспользоваться чистым CSS:

```
.yourclass
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Или (менее правильно) без класса с CSS3:

```
[id^="index"]
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Или воспользоваться советом [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre).

Comment: а если элементов неизвестное кол-во, то:

    $('[id*="index"]')

- [Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: @Spectre: ... но тогда лучшим решением был бы, вероятно, общий class.

Comment: безусловно